# What does (NSString *)name mean?

Tags: objective-c

I was going through an Objective-C book to learn, and came across a notation that I don't particularly recognize:
A pointer to "name" is created in the header as an instance variable.

```
NSString *name;
```

Then, in one of the function declarations, it says:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name atFrequency:(double)freq;
```

I understand that this is an instance method called `initWithName:atFrequency:`, but I don't understand the meaning of the argument `(NSString*)name`.
Any help would he greatly appreciated!

Comment: The thing in parentheses is the type of the parameter.  There are two parameters, `initWithName:` and `atFrequency:`.

Comment: If you aren't learning Objective C at the moment, stop and get a book.

Comment: This is entirely analogous to the formal parms in C or Java:  `int functionName(char* a, double b)`.  (The `(id)` is the return type -- `id` is sort of equivalent to Java `Object` or C `void*`.)

Comment: @HotLicks The parameter's names are `name` and `freq`. `initWithName:` and `atFrequency` are parts of the selector's name.

Comment: If you are reading a book that is supposed to teach you and it has confused you instead, try a different book.

Comment: @omz - Depends on your point of view.  C and Java do not have named parameters.  Objective-C does.

Answer (score 1):

The two things called `name` are utterly unrelated. One (the first) is, as you say, an instance variable. The other is a method parameter, a local reference to the first argument supplied in the method call. So if anyone ever says

```
[[MyClass alloc] initWithName:@"howdy" atFrequency:2];
```

then *inside* the body of the `initWithName:atFrequency:` method, there will be a variable `name` with a value `@"howdy"` (and a variable `freq` with a value `2.0`).

However, this is frowned on. Your local variable is overshadowing an instance variable. That's unwise, and in fact I would expect the compiler to warn.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, I now understand why it is there, however, I'm still confused about what the notation "(NSString *)name" means. Why is the astrix on the inside of the parenthesis? Why are there parenthesis in the first place? My book has failed to address this, so I don't even know what to search, so I came to the forum. Sorry if these kinds of questions are looked down upon.

Comment: I've written a better book. :) I suggest you start on page 1. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html

Comment: After you read chapter 1 you will know what the asterisk is. Then you can start on chapter 3: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html and you will learn how Objective-C methods are structured

Comment: Thank you so much! And also, I recognize your name, I've read a couple of your O'reilly books, they're great! I'll see how far this "apress" book takes me, and will probably just buy yours. Thanks again for this valuable resource.